# Turn on speaker amplifier when audio output selected

Tags: audio, kde, events, pipewire

I'm using KDE (plasma) with pipewire for audio.
I have some desktop speakers that need an amplifier with a power switch. I have a remote controlled power socket (shelly plug) to turn on the amplifier remotely. The power socket uses a HTTP (REST) interface. So it can be turned off/on via curl.

What I want is to switch on the amp, when I select it as audio output in KDE, and turn it off again, when I select my USB headphones as audio output.

[image]

What's the best way to do this?

- Use a systemd service to subscribe to pipewire events?
- Is there already software, that can do these things?